# How to export R shiny presentation to pdf or html

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, knitr

I built an interactive shiny presentation in Rstudio. Header of the .Rmd file is:

```
---
title: "title"
author: "author"
date: "date"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    mathjax: "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
runtime: shiny
---
```

I generate really nice slides with interactive elements. No problem. However, I cannot knit the document as html or pdf files. I think this's by design since I specifically select "runtime: shiny". Is there an alternative way to capture the presentation as pdf/html file even if it means loss of the interactive elements? The only solution I could come up with is capture a screenshot for every slide from the browser and save it separately. But this's laborious...

Answer (score 3):

You can Knit on-demand screenshots of the app by following [these instructions](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html).